# Записать php файл с текстом "$_SERVER text" через phpseclib: SSH2

Tags: php, ssh

Необходимо создать файл "index.php" в сессии ssh

Использую: "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~2.0",

```
$ssh = new SSH2("192.168.138.5", 22);
$ssh->login("user", "mypass");
$ssh->write("cd /home/user/\n");
$ssh->read('[prompt]');

$ssh->exec("cat > index.php <<EOF
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php');
EOF\n");
$ssh->disconnect();
unset($ssh);
```

Но получаю результат:

```
<?php
include(['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php');
```

Как записать текст вида "$_SERVER text" в файл через сессию ssh?

Comment: Здесь вопросы нужно задавать на русском языке.

Comment: Добавил комментарии на русском языке.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is (Решение):

```
include(\\$" . "_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php');
```